# Call For papers format help

Tags: ids

I’m intending to submit a personal project for a “call for papers” for an upcoming Con. I have a really interesting topic that I wanted to submit for the talk. I was hoping to gain some feed back on what a good layout/format would be for the paper.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sh1nu11bi, while this doesn't really fit as a question on the site, you could definitely try the [chat], I'm sure the folks there could give you some specific advice.

Answer (score 3):

The layout/format is usually determined by the con and specified in the CFP if not web based. As to the content of your CFP response i found this post to be very helpful when I started: https://www.defcon.org/html/links/dc-speakerscorner.html#nikita-cfp

Comment: My paper got accepted! Your advice was very significantly useful and very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Congratulations :)